# Does a neutral-to-ground voltage of 0.0 indicate a bootleg ground?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, grounding

As described [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36269/what-does-it-mean-when-there-is-a-voltage-difference-between-ground-and-neutral) (for example), in a correctly-wired receptacle, there will be a small potential difference between the neutral and ground wires that increases slightly with increasing load. I'm thinking that with a [bootleg ground](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/11275/43838), this voltage will always be 0 no matter how much current is running through the circuit. Is my reasoning correct? If so, is measuring the neutral-to-ground voltage a good way to test for the presence of a bootleg ground?

Backstory: I'm in the middle of buying a house in the US. The home inspector discovered that some of the three-pronged outlets had no ground wire. The listing claimed recent electrical upgrades, so I asked the seller to rewire these. I meant for this to be the starting point of a negotiation, but somewhat to my surprise, he agreed to do it. In the spirit of finding a cloud for every silver lining, I'm concerned this means he's planning to do something  like a bootleg ground to fool me and the inspector into thinking the problem is solved, and I'm trying to come up with a way to test for this without buying a $300 circuit analyzer.

Backstory update: It turns out the guy just replaced all the ungrounded outlets with GFCI boxes. Which is not exactly what I asked for, but good enough.

Comment: Do you still have room in your agreement to specify "NEC compliant repairs"? That would open the door to legal action if you discovered bootleg grounds. (Though it might also mean you end up with 2 prong plugs...)

Comment: @Aloysius It's too late to specify that for this round, but if I'm dissatisfied with the work as I see it, I could include it next time. Time is not on my side, though. At this point, unless problems are major, I'll probably just need to fix them myself (or demand a discount).

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you check resistance for bootleg instead of voltage difference.  If there is a bootleg, I'm guessing resistance will be about .001 ohms.

Comment: @diceless As long as noone complains about throwing the breaker, yes my meter can measure resistance. What kind of value should I expect if there is a legitimate ground?

Comment: @dlf how will that throw the breaker?

Comment: @diceless the circuit needs to be de-energized (manually) in order for my meter to measure resistance.

Comment: @dlf , in order to get accurate readings yes.  But in this case you are only looking to see if it is more than near zero.

Comment: @diceless I thought it was to protect the meter from getting fried. Is that not the case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29458/discussion-between-diceless-and-dlf).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way to check for the bootleg ground, is to open up one of the boxes and look at how the receptacle is wired.

Since the grounded (neutral) and grounding conductors are bonded at the service equipment, they should always be at about the same voltage potential.  If you had a long circuit, and an accurate meter, you might be able to measure a slight difference.

Since wire has a resistance, it's certainly possible to measure a voltage difference. However, a reading of 0 volts, does not necessarily mean there's a bootleg ground. The only way to know for sure, is to actually inspect the wiring.

Comment: Understood, but since I don't own the house yet, I'm not sure I'm technically allowed to do this. I'd like to anyway, and could insist on it as a condition for waiving my inspection contingency, but I'd rather avoid the whole discussion if possible.

Also, for what it's worth, I tested my multimeter on a correctly-wired outlet at work, and it was able to detect a 0.5V difference.

Comment: Removing a cover plate; and even pulling out a receptacle, I wouldn't think would be too invasive during a home inspection.  As for reading 0.5V on the circuit at work. How long is the circuit (along the wire)? Wire has a resistance, so it's definitely possible to get a reading. However, typically residential circuits aren't very long, so a reading of 0.1 - 0.2V might be high. I'm also guessing there's a bit of current flowing at work, whereas an empty house probably wouldn't have much load.

Comment: A home inspector won't unscrew face plates, but assuming you're willing to accept liability on your own walk through, most everyone looks the other way to the buyer doing a non-destructive check like this.

Comment: @BMitch My home inspector removed a few cover plates, when I was buying an older home. I guess it just depends on the inspector, and the area.

Comment: That seems to make sense. What about the converse--if I *do* see 1 volt or so, can I be pretty confident there is *not* a bootleg ground? (I guess the guy could have wired them together with a weak resistor in between, but I don't think I'm dealing with a criminal mastermind). And if I'm going to pick just one receptacle to take apart, I should prefer one that shows zero voltage over one that shows more?

Comment: Check any one of the receptacles the homeowner "fixed". If they're installing bootleg grounds, they're likely going to do the same on each receptacle. Or, remove the cover plate on **all** the receptacles that were "fixed". Or if you really want to be sure, ask the homeowner to show you the repair, or give you a copy of the bill for the repair (if an Electrician did the work).

Answer (score 4):

1. Get a big load, like a space heater or an old-school theatrical spotlight.
2. Plug it into each outlet in question and measure the voltage between neutral and ground.

   - If there's no difference, it's bootlegged.
   - If there is a significant difference, then it's probably done right.

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood of coming across 0.0 volts AC on a properly wired system is not great. So if you check them and do find 0.0 volts, it would warrant some investigation.

Comment: Disagree. If there is zero load on the circuit, the current through the neutral wire will be zero, and thus the voltage at the outlet's neutral will be zero.

Comment: Disagree. Even with no load on the circuit, you are not likely to actually get 0.0 volts. I just tried it on a completely empty, but powered up circuit and I show 24.8 mV. Even if you put your meter leads together, you still won't get 0.0. And I'm using a newly calibrated Fluke 789 Processmeter.

Comment: @edwardt If you have a $900 digital multimeter, you'll probably never measure 0.0000 volts neutral to ground. For most diyers with a $20 meter, 0.0 volts is definitely a possibility.

Comment: @Tester101 Fair enough. My job requires me to have the processmeter, so I haven't used a diyer meter in many many years. I can agree with you on that point.