# Bonding a neutral and ground together to get the power to work and junction box junction box

Tags: bedroom

My plugs won't work in some parts of my house. But if I go up in the attic To a junction box . The only way  I can get the power to work in thoses places is to put a jumper from the  neutral to the  ground  and everything works fine. It's the  craziest thing I've ever seen. Ive done some research on this. Some old timers say they did this in the older houses. So that's what I've done. And all is good. But I can't quite thinking about it. Please help.

I found this while researching:

> I am a real electrician and on most of the older homes a jumper from nutruls went to ground. I been playing out here with you guys. Now i will answer your last question if you run under ground plastic pvc you dont want to use a ground rod. The way your main house panel is you can come back off the subpanel nutrals with a extra wire to all your grounds in garage or shed. You need to learn the old way was just as good as the new way.l just dont ground the box and yes it does work. And yes the inspector does not mess with me any more im hard headed. And his oulet is wrong the ground and nutral should be in box and seperate wires should go to outlet. The new thing today is they have a crazy made up idea that a seperate ground is safer for lightning bullshit all most all of the old houses are still standing or fell down from old age. When lighting strikes a main service it will go right back to ground rod. Not come back up the nutrals. Lighting does not ever take the long path on under ground power to your house if you have one hell of a run it blows out the power tranformer on pole and a small charge back the ground on the main handles it as far as it comming back a nother 150 feet plus will never happen to far of a path.you got a better chance of seeing god did it for thirty years and all my garages and sheds are still standing.over head is different change the new law every building over head needs a ground rod.

Is this true.

Comment: Long story short, the ground should not be used to complete a circuit.  This could be indicative of more serious issues.

Comment: That's what I thought but a lot of people say yes if it's a house from the 50s

Comment: Frankly -- and I know this is classist -- I would hesitate to take any advice written that poorly without a ___lot___ of evidence that they knew their stuff. And in this case he doesn't .

Comment: You have an open neutral. Fix it properly.

Comment: Here is the source of that quote: http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/69003/22. You'll notice it has a score of -6, meaning that 6 people thought it "is not useful".

Answer (score 4):

The grounded (neutral) and grounding conductors, should only be connected together at the service equipment.  Using the grounding conductors as current carrying conductors is dangerous, and could lead to property damage, personal injury, and/or death.

If you're having a problem with the grounded (neutral) conductors, you should fix the problem. Trying to bodge something together, is **not** the way to go. Especially when dealing with electricity.