# Neutral wire is not working

Tags: wiring

I am trying to change outside light fixture and identified the ground and neutral wires from the fixture are connected to ground wire from the home. The neutral wire was not used at all. I try to connect neutral from new fixture to neutral from home and ground to ground and hot to hot wires and the new fixture did not work. If I connect neutral form the fixture to ground wire from home it is working. So, is it OK to connect  neutral and ground form the fixture to ground wire from home ? Does it cause any problem in future?

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11275/why-does-this-receptacle-have-the-ground-tied-to-the-neutral

Comment: No, it's not wise nor safe to connect neutral and ground. You'll need to trace the cable back until you find out where that neutral does or doesn't go. It's hard for us to say from here.

Comment: Do you have a good wire? You can test it against a 3 prong extension cord. Neutral and ground should only be connected at the first switched (main) panel, not at random points throughout the system

Answer (score 2):

You have a open neutral somewhere. If you know what circuit that issue is in on:
 Look too see if there's anything plugged into any receptacles and unplug it ( or them ). If you find there was, *then* go back & check to see if there's still "hot" power on that white wire...
If there's no longer power on that white wire, *shut that circuit off* then open up the closest receptacle box ( pull out the receptacle ) and inspect it.... 
If the above didn't find it, go to the next receptacle and the next and so on until you find the culprit.

Open up every box related to that circuit. Even your main panel box....and you'll check to see if all the "whites" are connected on the common terminal... That's a start, and hopefully a "finish" too.

Good luckBe safe.